# Running the composer remove package name / composer require package name from bash file not working

Tags: php, composer-php

I am facing a unique issue as i have created a script to install package using my api which is in php file and which used the shell_exec to run a bash file and this bash file is used to install package or remove the package.

But These two command are not working but in i run the composer -v or any other command it give output. so is there any permision for that.

```
   $projectPath = './uninstall.sh  '.$name.'  '.$version;
   $page = shell_exec($projectPath);

   .sh file
composer remove $1 $2  --- not working
composer -v     -- working
```

Comment: Your shell script file seems incomplete: did you put in a hashbang header (`#!/bin/sh`)? Also, when you say "not working", you mean - no output at all, or is some error message is shown - and if so, what error?

Comment: @Guss not output at all it not install any package or on remove just remove the name from package.json but not remove the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `composer remove` does indeed supposed to only remove the requirement from the `compose.json` file - it does not remove the directory.

Regarding install (which you didn't demonstrate), I'm guessing there is some error during installation which isn't showing.

**Important**: the `shell_exec()` command does not capture the "standard error" stream of the executed shell (this is poorly documented in [the `shell_exec()` function reference](https://www.php.net/shell_exec)). Instead, for commands that output only to stderr, it returns `NULL` - which it also returns if the executed shell command returned with a non-zero result code, discarding all of the actual output from that shell command, so you often miss the actual error.

If the shell command run using `shell_exec()` outputs to the standard error stream, that would be streamed to the terminal connected to the running PHP script, or to the server error stream (usually an error log) if running under a server API - so I recommend checking that.

That being said, you should probably not use `shell_exec()` for any non-trivial things, especially things that can fail. `system()` is much better as it doesn't return `NULL` for commands that end with a non-zero exit code, but the best choice is obviously the much more complicated to use `proc_open()`.